# How to shrink parts of a vector image in either Inkscape and/or Illustrator CS6?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, vector, svg, resize

Lets assume I have an .svg/.eps/.ai file like this (viewed in Inkscape):

[image: Animal ears]

What I want to do now is to shrink those ears to half of the size while they should still stay in their position on the head. They should also keep their basic shape just be smaller.

Obviously I can not move the nodes one by one (sorry if this is a noob question I am a programmer and tried/googled a lot, nothing worked).

Comment: This isnt entirely trivial as you would need to make some exra geometry. But i would eithercscale them and draw the recrevealed pieces or use some of the defirmation tools.

Comment: @joojaa Deformation is already a good word, thank you. Stumbled upon "envelopes" and "free transform" tools I will investigate further research in this direction.

Comment: @joojaa, that seems like an answer to me, the same one I would have fired off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is for Inkscape.

1. Select the paths using the Edit Paths by Nodes tool
2. Click and drag to select the nodes you want to resize
3. In the toolbar along the top, hit the *Show Transform Handles* button
4. Resize using the handles, move into position using the arrow keys on your keyboard.
5. You will likely have to manually adjust the path where the head joins with the ear.

Here's a very simplified example

[image]

Comment: This will help me get the task done with playing around a little bit, thank you!